# Laravel Intervention Image Class - Class 'Image' not found

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to install `intervention/image` from composer, but after installation I get this error:

```
Class 'Image' not found
```

**1: install via composer:**

```
composer require intervention/image
```

**2: add to providers array:**

```
'Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider'
```

**3: add to aliases array:**

```
'Image' => 'Intervention\Image\Facades\Image'
```

**4: update composer:**

```
composer update
```

**5: publish:**

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProviderLaravel5"
```

**public result:**

```
Nothing to publish for tag [].
```

**6: autoload:**

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy file config.php in folder /vender/intervention/image/src/config/config.php to /config/
   and rename config.php to image.php
2. Update config

   php artisan config:cache

Comment: Had the same "nothing to publish" issue, and while referencing Image via "use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;" works, it definitely feels like a hack so I kept looking. As soon as I put image.php in /config it started working using the Image alias as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `Image` facade into a namespaced class, you should try this

```
// import class
use Image;

// then
Image::make('public/foo.jpg');
```

or

```
\Image::make('public/foo.jpg');
```

Comment: adding "\" symbol really helped me on Laravel 5.3 ant Intervention 2.3. After hours of searching! :)